# Shrinking Picker to fit content and no larger

Tags: swiftui

I am developing a MacOS app using SwiftUI and would like a Picker to shrink to only show its label and content, and a Spacer to take up the rest of the view, but I'm not sure what the correct way to do this. The code looks something like this:

```
HStack{
    Text("hello")
    Text("more text")
    Spacer()
    Picker(selection: self.$stuff, label: Text("some stuff:")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< self.getStuff().count) {
            Text(self.getStuff()[$0])
        }
    }
}
```

and the Picker is expanded to take up as much room as possible. I would prefer that the picker take up the minimum amount of space and the Spacer to take up the remaining space.

Edit: photo:

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of what you currently get?

Comment: added image, as you can see the picker takes up a ton of space, though the texts for the picker choices are "item1" and "item2", no long text exists.

Comment: is the same even with using `.frame`? which environment versions do you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `.scaledToFit` to fit it to content as below

[image: swiftui macOS picker/popup]

```
    Picker(selection: self.$stuff, label: Text("some stuff:")) {
        ForEach(0 ..< self.getStuff().count) {
            Text(self.getStuff()[$0])
        }
    }
    .scaledToFit()
//  .frame(width: 160) // < alternate approach - give explicit desired width
```

Comment: You know, I tried that, but it ends up eating up the label of the Picker and ends up turning it from "some stuff" into "som..."

Comment: It might be my version of Xcode. I'll try to upgrade. The alternate approach, using a fixed frame size works, so I'll stick with that for now.

Comment: Adding .fixedSize() to the Text label fixes the ellipsis issue @user3577166